# Exporting Cursor to CSV File. CSV File Missing

Tags: android, csv, export, android-room

I have a customer database that uses the Room Database Architecture. For background, I have a Customer Entity, a Customer Dao, a Customer Data Repository and a Customer View Model. The application I have created has those 4 components working. Now I need to download the data to a CSV file and I am looking for the best approach to do this.

So far, I have come up on this solution based on my research so far.

1. Have a CSV file write utility (got this from the internet)

   ```
     import java.io.IOException;
     import java.io.PrintWriter;
     import java.io.Writer;

     public class CSVWriter {
           private PrintWriter pw;
           private char separator;
           private char quotechar;
           private char escapechar;
           private String lineEnd;

           /** The character used for escaping quotes. */
           public static final char DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER = '"';

           /** The default separator to use if none is supplied to the constructor. */
           public static final char DEFAULT_SEPARATOR = ',';

           /**
           * The default quote character to use if none is supplied to the
           * constructor.
           */
           public static final char DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER = '"';

           /** The quote constant to use when you wish to suppress all quoting. */
           public static final char NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER = '\u0000';

           /** The escape constant to use when you wish to suppress all escaping. */
           public static final char NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER = '\u0000';

           /** Default line terminator uses platform encoding. */
           public static final String DEFAULT_LINE_END = "\n";

           /**
            * Constructs CSVWriter using a comma for the separator.
            *
            * @param writer
            *            the writer to an underlying CSV source.
            */
            public CSVWriter(Writer writer) {
                  this(writer, DEFAULT_SEPARATOR, DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER,
                     DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER, DEFAULT_LINE_END);
            } 

            /**
             * Constructs CSVWriter with supplied separator, quote char, escape char and 
                line ending.
             *
             * @param writer
             *            the writer to an underlying CSV source.
             * @param separator
             *            the delimiter to use for separating entries
             * @param quotechar
             *            the character to use for quoted elements
             * @param escapechar
             *            the character to use for escaping quotechars or escapechars
             * @param lineEnd
             *               the line feed terminator to use
             */
             public CSVWriter(Writer writer, char separator, char quotechar, char 
          escapechar, String lineEnd) {
                   this.pw = new PrintWriter(writer);
                   this.separator = separator;
                   this.quotechar = quotechar;
                   this.escapechar = escapechar;
                   this.lineEnd = lineEnd;
           }

           /**
           * Writes the next line to the file.
           *
           * @param nextLine
           *            a string array with each comma-separated element as a separate
           *            entry.
           */
           public void writeNext(String[] nextLine) {

                  if (nextLine == null)
                  return;

                  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                  for (int i = 0; i < nextLine.length; i++) {

                         if (i != 0) {
                              sb.append(separator);
                         }  

                         String nextElement = nextLine[i];
                         if (nextElement == null)
                              continue;
                         if (quotechar !=  NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER)
                              sb.append(quotechar);
                         for (int j = 0; j < nextElement.length(); j++) {
                              char nextChar = nextElement.charAt(j);
                              if (escapechar != NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER && nextChar == quotechar) {
                                 sb.append(escapechar).append(nextChar);
                              } else if (escapechar != NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER && nextChar == 
                                     escapechar) {
                                 sb.append(escapechar).append(nextChar);
                              } else {
                                 sb.append(nextChar);
                              }
                         }
                         if (quotechar != NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER)
                              sb.append(quotechar);
                  }

             sb.append(lineEnd);
             pw.write(sb.toString());

             }

             /**
             * Flush underlying stream to writer.
             *
             * @throws IOException if bad things happen
             */
             public void flush() throws IOException {
                  pw.flush();
             }

          /**
           * Close the underlying stream writer flushing any buffered content.
           *
           * @throws IOException if bad things happen
            *
           */
           public void close() throws IOException {
               pw.flush();
               pw.close();
           }

       }
   ```
2. I accessed my Customer View Model

   ```
   private CustomerViewModel mCustomerViewModel;
   private Cursor mCursor;

   mCustomerViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(CustomerViewModel.class);
   mCustomerViewModel.getAllCustomers().observe(this, new Observer<List<Customer>>() {
       @Override
       public void onChanged(List<Customer> customers) {
           mCursor = getCursorFromList(customers);
       }
   });
   ```
3. I converted the List to a Cursor using this getCursorFromList online.

   ```
   public Cursor getCursorFromList(List<Customer> customers) {
        MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(
           new String[]{"id", "customerCode", "branchCode", "telephone"}
        );

       for (Customer customer : customers) {
            cursor.newRow()
               .add("id", customer.getId())
               .add("customerCode", customer.getCustomerCode())
               .add("branchCode", customer.getBranchCode())
               .add("telephone", customer.getTelephone());
        }

        return cursor;
     }
   ```
4. Finally, I used the CSV writer to write the Cursor to the file.

   ```
           File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "");
           if (!exportDir.exists()) {
               exportDir.mkdirs();
           }

           File file = new File(exportDir, "customer.csv");
           try {
               file.createNewFile();
               CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
               csvWrite.writeNext(mCursor.getColumnNames());
               while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
                   //Which column you want to exprort
                   String arrStr[] = {mCursor.getString(0), mCursor.getString(1), mCursor.getString(2)};
                   Log.v("MainActivity1", arrStr[0] + arrStr[1] + arrStr[2]);
                   csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);
               }
               csvWrite.close();
               mCursor.close();
           } catch (Exception sqlEx) {
               Log.e("MainActivity1", sqlEx.getMessage(), sqlEx);
           }
   ```
5. Finally in Android manifest I have the following permission:
         < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

The command Log.v("MainActivity1", arrStr[0] + arrStr[1] + arrStr[2]); shows all the data in my Log file.. but the file is no where to be found. No error is coming out. I am able to retrieve the data and show in my log but it seems either the CSV writer is not working or am I not getting the right directory or something. Every help is needed!

Answer (score 0):

it works.. the code i copied online lacks the folder name:
File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/TestFolder");